# rk3328 soc boot stuck at waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p2

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I cloned this repo [[https://github.com/flatmax/buildroot.rockchip](https://stackoverflow.com)]
to use as a starting point to build a minimal embedded linux for these boards (https://www.olimex.com/Products/SOM/RK3328/RK3328-SOM-1G/ ) and https://www.olimex.com/Products/SOM/RK3328/RK3328-SOM-EVB/open-source-hardware.

I'm new to embedded linux. Brand new.

I created new u-boot and kernel device trees by mostly stripping almost everything out of the rock-pi-e.dts device tree.  I left in the PMIC, cpu's, emmc, sdmmc, uart2, uart1.

Buildroot finishes compilation just fine. Or rather, 'make ' with no target completes without complaining about patches or kernel headers or missing dts or anything.  and after writing the sd card with dd I Inserted the SDXC card into the board and applied power. (all per the instructions of the flatmax/buildroot site)

uboot seems to be fine to me.

I have a 5V/3A power supply and I monitored the power rails using my ociliscope.  I tried three different SD cards. I did change the bootarg for /dev/mmcbl0p2 to /dev//mmcblk1p2 because the error message before was about /dev/mmcblk0p2.. and I don't have an emmc module.

here is the boot log from the debug uart

**EDIT
Actual bootlog really attached now**

**EDIT:**
**kernel command line:**
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 earlyprintk console=ttyS2,115200n8 rw rootwait

Here is the bootlog
U-Boot 2022.04 (Sep 02 2023 - 22:17:56 -0400)

```
Model: olimex RK3328 
DRAM:  2 GiB
PMIC:  RK8050 (on=0x10, off=0x00)
Core:  206 devices, 17 uclasses, devicetree: separate
MMC:   mmc@ff500000: 1, mmc@ff520000: 0
Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial@ff130000
Out:   serial@ff130000
Err:   serial@ff130000
Model: olimex RK3328 
Net:   Net Initialization Skipped
No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1 is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
Found U-Boot script /boot.scr
1070 bytes read in 3 ms (347.7 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 00500000
loading boot vars
31 bytes read in 2 ms (14.6 KiB/s)
setting boot args
47925 bytes read in 7 ms (6.5 MiB/s)
31717888 bytes read in 1383 ms (21.9 MiB/s)
loading overlay module-overlay-rk3308
Failed to load 'rockchip/overlays/module-overlay-rk3308.dtbo'
Moving Image from 0x2080000 to 0x2200000, end=40d0000
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 01f00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x1f00000
   Loading Device Tree to 000000007decd000, end 000000007df41fff ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
Linux version 5.11.22 (david@david-System-Product-Name) (aarch64-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc.br_real (Buildroot 2023.08-rc2-13-g6d8deb4b23) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.40) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 1 17:26:14 EDT 2023
Machine model: olimex RK3328 
efi: UEFI not found.
NUMA: No NUMA configuration found
NUMA: Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000200000-0x000000007fffffff]
NUMA: NODE_DATA [mem 0x7fbc2c00-0x7fbc4fff]
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x0000000000200000-0x000000007fffffff]
  DMA32    empty
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000000200000-0x000000007fffffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000200000-0x000000007fffffff]
cma: Reserved 32 MiB at 0x0000000079000000
psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
psci: PSCIv1.0 detected in firmware.
psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs
psci: Trusted OS migration not required
psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.0
percpu: Embedded 23 pages/cpu s56536 r8192 d29480 u94208
Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU0
CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 845719
Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 515592
Policy zone: DMA
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 earlyprintk console=ttyS2,115200n8 rw rootwait
Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
Memory: 1990248K/2095104K available (14592K kernel code, 2878K rwdata, 7620K rodata, 5760K init, 493K bss, 72088K reserved, 32768K cma-reserved)
SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
rcu:    RCU event tracing is enabled.
rcu:    RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
    Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x348/0x508 with crng_init=0
arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 24.00MHz (phys).
clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x588fe9dc0, max_idle_ns: 440795202592 ns
sched_clock: 56 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 4398046511097ns
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 48.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=96000)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
LSM: Security Framework initializing
Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
EFI services will not be available.
smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU1
CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd034]
Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU2
CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd034]
Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU3
CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd034]
smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL1 Support
CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
alternatives: patching kernel code
devtmpfs: initialized
KASLR disabled due to lack of seed
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
DMI not present or invalid.
NET: Registered protocol family 16
DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
audit: type=2000 audit(0.048:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'
cpuidle: using governor menu
hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
ASID allocator initialised with 65536 entries
Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio0 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio1 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio2 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio3 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio0 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio1 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio2 is not valid
rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: bank gpio3 is not valid
HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 32.0 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 64.0 KiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
ACPI: Interpreter disabled.
iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
FPGA manager framework
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
pnp: PnP ACPI: disabled
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP idents hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 1024 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
UDP hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a53 PMU driver, 7 counters available
kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 40 bits
kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ9
kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
Initialise system trusted keyrings
workingset: timestamp_bits=42 max_order=19 bucket_order=0
squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Key type id_resolver registered
Key type id_legacy registered
nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
9p: Installing v9fs 9p2000 file system support
Key type asymmetric registered
Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 245)
io scheduler mq-deadline registered
io scheduler kyber registered
EINJ: ACPI disabled.
dma-pl330 ff1f0000.dma-controller: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-241330
dma-pl330 ff1f0000.dma-controller:  DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-20 Num_Events-16
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
ff120000.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xff120000 (irq = 18, base_baud = 1500000) is a 16550A
ff130000.serial: ttyS2 at MMIO 0xff130000 (irq = 19, base_baud = 1500000) is a 16550A
printk: console [ttyS2] enabled
SuperH (H)SCI(F) driver initialized
msm_serial: driver initialized
loop: module loaded
megasas: 07.714.04.00-rc1
libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
thunder_xcv, ver 1.0
thunder_bgx, ver 1.0
nicpf, ver 1.0
hclge is initializing
hns3: Hisilicon Ethernet Network Driver for Hip08 Family - version
hns3: Copyright (c) 2017 Huawei Corporation.
e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver
igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
igbvf: Intel(R) Gigabit Virtual Function Network Driver
igbvf: Copyright (c) 2009 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
sky2: driver version 1.30
VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
ehci-orion: EHCI orion driver
ehci-exynos: EHCI Exynos driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
ohci-exynos: OHCI Exynos driver
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
i2c /dev entries driver
dw_wdt ff1a0000.watchdog: No valid TOPs array specified
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 35,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
9pnet: Installing 9P2000 support
Key type dns_resolver registered
registered taskstats version 1
Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
debugfs: Directory 'power-domain' with parent 'pm_genpd' already present!
debugfs: Directory 'power-domain' with parent 'pm_genpd' already present!
ALSA device list:
  No soundcards found.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
rockchip-pm-domain ff100000.syscon:power-controller: failed to get ack on domain 'power-domain', val=0x88220
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 35,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 35,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 35,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dw-apb-uart ff130000.serial: forbid DMA for kernel console
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 35,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p2...
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_rockchip ff520000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 36,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
dwmmc_rockchip ff500000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 35,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
```

**EDIT: ADD DTS**

```
    / SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0+ OR MIT)

 * (C) Copyright 2020 Chen-Yu Tsai <wens@csie.org>
 *
 * Based on ./rk3328-rock64.dts, which is
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2017 PINE64
*/
 

#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>
#include <dt-bindings/input/input.h>
#include <dt-bindings/leds/common.h>
#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/rockchip.h>

#include "rk3328.dtsi"

 

/ {
    model = "olimex RK3328 ";
    compatible =  "rockchip,rk3328";
    aliases {
        mmc0 = &sdmmc;
        mmc1 = &emmc;
    };
    chosen {
        stdout-path = "serial2:1500000n8";  // dEBUG UART 2 ON OLIMEX EVB
    };
    
    vcc_sys: vcc-sys {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "vcc_sys";
        regulator-always-on;
        regulator-boot-on;
        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
    };
    
    

    

};


&sdmmc {
    bus-width = <4>;
    cap-mmc-highspeed;
    cap-sd-highspeed;
    disable-wp;
    broken-cd;
    max-frequency = <150000000>;
    num-slots = <1>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&sdmmc0_clk &sdmmc0_cmd &sdmmc0_dectn &sdmmc0_bus4>;
    supports-sd;
    sd-uhs-sdr12;
    sd-uhs-sdr25;
    sd-uhs-sdr50;
    sd-uhs-sdr104;
    status = "okay";
    vmmc-supply = <&vcc_io>;
};  
    
&uart2 {
    status = "okay";
};

&uart1{
    status = "okay";
};
&emmc {
    bus-width = <8>;
    cap-mmc-highspeed;
    mmc-ddr-1_8v;
    mmc-hs200-1_8v;
    non-removable;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_clk>, <&emmc_cmd>, <&emmc_bus8>;
    vmmc-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    vqmmc-supply = <&vcc18_emmc>;
    status = "okay";
};

    


&cpu0 {
    cpu-supply = <&vdd_cpu>;
};
&cpu1 {
    cpu-supply = <&vdd_cpu>;
};
&cpu2 {
    cpu-supply = <&vdd_cpu>;
};
&cpu3 {
    cpu-supply = <&vdd_cpu>;
};


&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";
    rk805: pmic@18 {
        compatible = "rockchip,rk805";
        reg = <0x18>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
        interrupts = <6 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
        #clock-cells = <1>;
        clock-output-names = "xin32k", "rk805-clkout2";
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pmic_int_l>;
        rockchip,system-power-controller;
        wakeup-source;
        vcc1-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc2-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc3-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc4-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc5-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        vcc6-supply = <&vcc_io >;
        regulators {
            vdd_log: DCDC_REG1 {
                regulator-name = "vdd_log";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <712500>;  // HOW TO DETERMINE THIS?
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1450000>; // HOW TO DETERMINE THIS?
                regulator-ramp-delay = <12500>; // HOW TO DETERMINE THIS?
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1000000>; // HOW TO DETERMINE THIS?
                };
            };
            vdd_cpu: DCDC_REG2 { // was vdd_arm 
                regulator-name = "vdd_cpu";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <712500>;   //RK805 Datasheet pg 14 buck 2
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1450000>; //RK805 Datasheet pg 14 buck 2
                regulator-ramp-delay = <12500>; //RK805 Datasheet pg 14 buck 2
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <950000>;   // HOW TO DETERMINE THIS?
                };
            };
            vcc_ddr: DCDC_REG3 {
                regulator-name = "vcc_ddr";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                };
            };
            vcc_io: DCDC_REG4 {
                regulator-name = "vcc_io";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <3300000>;
                };
            };
            vcc_18: LDO_REG1 {
                regulator-name = "vcc_18";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1800000>;
                };
            };
            vcc18_emmc: LDO_REG2 {
                regulator-name = "vcc18_emmc";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1800000>;
                };
            };
            vdd_10: LDO_REG3 {
                regulator-name = "vdd_10";
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1000000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1000000>;
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1000000>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

&io_domains {
    pmuio-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    vccio1-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    vccio2-supply = <&vcc18_emmc>;
    vccio3-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    vccio4-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    vccio5-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    vccio6-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    status = "okay";
};

&pinctrl {

    pmic {
        pmic_int_l: pmic-int-l {
            rockchip,pins = <2 RK_PA3 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_up>;
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: You probably removed too much from the Device Tree. BTW there is no boot log attached to your post.

Comment: It is also possible that you have not set all the necessary kernel configuration options.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the reply.  I have the device tree up there now.  I can point to the schematics on why I changed what I did.  Also I can post a diff of the rock-pi-e.dts that is in the linux source.

Comment: The boot log and **.dts** file aren't as useful without working/functional versions for comparison. The SDMMC interface is rather complex (to me anyway), and can be configured in a variety of voltages & clock frequencies. You seem to be missing a `sdmmc-regulator` node in your **.dts**, which can supply power to the medium.